# How to serialize into JSON message in MassTransit and store it, so that it can be sent at a later time without any changes

Tags: json, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to find a good way to serialize MassTransit messages (envelope and all) and store the messages outside of MassTransit. I then want to be able to send the messages at some point in time with MassTransit without any extra serialization.
Is there a way to do this with MassTransit and RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Quartz.NET, MassTransit has built-in support for scheduling messages.

The usage is documented: http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/scheduling/scheduling_api.html

There is also a self-hosting (using Topshelf) service for Quartz.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/develop/src/MassTransit.Host.Quartz

Comment: Thank you @chris. I have found the scheduler implementation. The scheduler implementation is only one of the implementations we where looking at that will need the message storage functionality. I was using it as an example here as it is the easiest one to explain. Is there a way to serialize MassTransit messages, envelope and all, and then send them at a later date with no extra serialization needed?

Comment: Yeah look at the Quartz Integration code, it's doing the same thing. You should be able to go from there to do something for your own use. It includes code to save the envelope as well as send it to the transport later.